# Remove onclick function call w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an icon on a page, what when clicked is calling a function from an external JS file.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="myCheck"/>

<img src="icon.png" id="myIcon" onclick="myFunction)(this,null,null)" />
```

I need to add a functionality to disable this click when a checkbox is checked, and allow click and calling the JS function if the checkbox is not selected.

Tried this but it does not seem to work. What am I missing?

```
$("#myCheck").prop("checked", true).click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

UPDATE: since I do not have much control over code that is not in the header in this particular case, and can not remove  onclick="myFunction)(this,null,null) from img tag, is there still a way to disable click action if the checkbox is selected. Perhaps I can remove HTML. What would JS be considered here? It's not an attribute...

Comment: that binds a click event to the check box, and stops *the checkbox's event* from propagating.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to, instead of disabling the click event, to simply check for the value of the checkbox before proceeding with the `myFunction` code?

```
function myFunction() {
    if (!document.getElementById('myCheck').checked) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

Edit/Disclaimer: Technically the above example code doesn't provide a good example of separation of concerns because it gives knowledge to the `myFunction` code about the existence of `myCheck`.  Depending on your use case this may or may not be a good design pattern.  Ktash's answer provides an alternate solution that while it uses more code is theoretically better separated (though also requiring jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

Hows about:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="myCheck"/>
<img src="icon.png" id="myIcon" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    function iconClick() {
        alert('Clicked Icon!');
    }

    $('#myIcon').click(iconClick);

    $("#myCheck").change(function(e) {
        if (this.checked) $('#myIcon').click(iconClick);
        else $('#myIcon').unbind('click');
    });
});
```

You can see it working at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upWDY/4/).

Comment: These are all great solutions, however I can not remove  onclick="myFunction)(this,null,null) from IMG tag. Is there still a way to disable that JS onclick? UPDATED my question.

Comment: @santa then you would have to do something like T. Stone's solution

Comment: But again, that would require moving function call from img to the header... won't it?

Comment: @santa no it would require modifying `myFunction()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing an `onclick` attribute, do the following in JavaScript

```
$('#myIcon').click(function (e) {
    if($('#myCheck').is(':checked')) myFunction(this,null,null);
});
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir Oops, yeah, @Chad got it for me (thanks), but I meant `$('#myIcon')`. I spend too much time switching between prototype and jQuery lol

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="myCheck"/>

<img src="icon.png" id="myIcon" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function ($) {
    var checkbox = $('#myCheck'),
        icon = $('#myIcon'),
        fireEvent,
        myFunction;

    fireEvent = function() {
        if(checkbox.is(':checked')){
            icon.off('click');
        } else {
            icon.on('click', myFunction);
        }
    };

    myFunction = function() {
        console.log('I just was clicked!');
    };
    $(function() {
        fireEvent();
        checkbox.on('click', fireEvent);
    });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```